# Clockwise increasing labeling of a planar graph's edges

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory

Suppose a planar graph is drawn on a plane, and we are labeling the edges, i.e., assigning positive integers to the them. The requirement is that for every "polygon", its edge labels must increase in the counter-clockwise direction starting from a certain edge among them. Below is an illustration of two attempts:

[image: failed attempt]

[image: success attempt]

The question is whether it is always possible to do such labeling. What's the necessary and sufficient conditions. If possible, I also want to know how many possible ways of labeling are there. The last question may be hard, so analysis of the possibility itself is also fine.

**Addition** If there are $n$ edges, you can only use integers in $[1, n]$. Certainly, you will use all of them without repetition.

**Addition 2** The title should really be "counter-clockwise" to be consistent with the illustration. I do realize that one consequence of the increasing counter-clockwise labeling for each polygon ('s edge) is that the outer boundary's label would increase counter-clockwise, this is kind of Stoke's theorem on a discrete graph.

Comment: By "polygons" you just mean the faces of the graph, right? And are you counting the outer face too, right?

Comment: @MikePierce Yes, I mean just the faces (the smallest cells formed by the edges). No compound larger ones are considered.

Comment: Also, do you have to use *consecutive* integers? So like if you have $n$ edges then are you only allowed to use the labels $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$.?

Comment: @MikePierce Very good point, I missed this in the questions. YES, if there are n edges, you can only use {1, ..., n}.

Comment: Interesting question. No answer track. Is it linked to Voronoi tessellations ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. Voronoi tessellation is just a special case, for this question any spatial partition (no gap, no overlap) could serve as the subject to be labelled.